# Mandando dados de uma tableView para outra

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Gostaria de passar valores de uma tableView para outra.

Peguei uma valor atraves do indexPath.row, gostaria de enviar o valor para outra tableView para que nela possa fazer um switch para aparecer diferentes views.

Comment: Eduardo, ficou um pouco confuso de entender o seu contexto e o que você espera realizar. Em uma tela só você possui duas `UITableView` e a intenção é ao selecionar uma linha da primeira tabela, passar este valor para a outra tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Vlw Galera pelas respostas, mas em algumas situaçoes em swift prefiro nao usar o init. Entao resolvi dessa maneira.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var ProxViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewControllerAnalseOP1
        ProxViewController.indice = self.indiceClicado
}
```

Isso ai, se nao intenderem podem perguntar sobre o cogido, :)

Comment: Opa, peço desculpas por escrever em Obj-c, vou editá-la para Swift.

Comment: Tranquilo, se nao for muito incomodo seria uma boa deixar aqui. Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Existe também a possibilidade de armazenar os dados em uma classe Singleton, que é um padrão de projeto, se caso for preciso que os dados estejam disponíveis para diversas classes utilizarem. Como exemplo, classes que armazenam dados de sessão de usuário.
Segue um link de exemplo de como fazer, assim com explicações mais detalhadas: [Design Patterns in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1)